# Variable dustjs partial name

Tags: dust.js

I am setting up some heavy split testing using dust.js on my single page app.

The base template looks like (simplified):

```
{>"layouts/master" /}

{<body}
<div id="container">
  {?home}{>homeWelcome/}{/home}
</div>
{/body}
```

What I'm trying to do is have a folder containing N versions of the homeWelcome partial, and send N through the model to select the right template, like so :

```
{<body}
<div id="container">
  {?home}{>/splits/homeWelcome_{partialNumber}/}{/home}
</div>
{/body}
```

But it (unsurprisingly) doesn't compile.

I could send params to the one homeWelcome template, and have all my splits in there but some are radically different from the others and it'd make for one hell of a long file.

In addition to that, I want to be able to add/remove partials in the splits directory dynamically (partialNumber is a rand from 1 to the number of files in the dir).

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add double quotes around the partial name and dust will happily parse the string before including a partial.

Note that partial names don't necessarily relate to folder structure, but I'm assuming you are compiling your templates with the appropriate names.

Comment: Duh, double quotes... Thanks bro, it works perfectly, much appreciated!